# How can a choice box, checkbox, and text field be implemented into one button with JavaFX

Tags: javafx, checkbox, textarea, textfield

I'm trying to create a program that can take data from a choicebox, checkbox, and text field and put it into a single textArea as output. How can I have all the information combine from one button. I have already created the choicebox, checkbox, and text fields.

-There are two text fields. One of them takes a name, and the other takes a number. The number will determine how many times the program is looped.

-The checkbox will take what kind of prefix to put in front of the name (Mr, Mrs, etc).

-The choicebox give options on what follow up statement will be given. (How was your day?, I like your hat, etc)

After clicking the button, the program would display something like this in a textArea if the number in the textField had an input of 2

> "1Hello Mr. Johnson. How was your day?"

> "2Hello Mr. Johnson. How was your day?"

This is what I have in the button event handler. It only implements the text fields

```
 private class CreateButtonHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        int i = 0;
        String myString = number.getText();
        int foo = Integer.parseInt(myString);
        do {
             OutputTxtArea.setText(OutputTxtArea.getText() + (i + 1) + "Hello " + firstNameTxtFld.getText() + "\n");
        } while(i<foo);
}
}
```

Comment: You can get the selected value from the `ChoiceBox` by calling...`getValue()`. And you can call `CheckBox.isSelected()` to determine if the `CheckBox` is ... selected.

Comment: And I'd also recommend learning about the Java [naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) and stick to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bindings!

Things are easier to do if you separate the layout from the data and the actions, and then have the actions work on the data.  This leaves the screen to just be a screen, and you're not worried about "how do I deal with getting the CheckBox values?" kind of questions.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Greeter extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Model model = new Model();
        ChoiceBox<String> questionChoiceBox = new ChoiceBox<>(model.questionList);
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea("");
        textArea.textProperty().bind(model.greetingProperty());
        VBox vBox = new VBox(20,
                             createBoundCheckBox("Miss", model.isMissProperty()),
                             createBoundCheckBox("Missus", model.isMissusProperty()),
                             createBoundCheckBox("Mister", model.isMisterProperty()),
                             questionChoiceBox,
                             createBoundTextField(model.nameProperty()),
                             createBoundTextField(model.loopCountProperty()),
                             textArea);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vBox, 200, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @NotNull
    private Node createBoundCheckBox(String label, BooleanProperty boundProperty) {
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(label);
        boundProperty.bind(checkBox.selectedProperty());
        return checkBox;
    }

    private Node createBoundTextField(StringProperty boundProperty) {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        boundProperty.bind(textField.textProperty());
        return textField;
    }

    class Model {
        private StringProperty loopCount = new SimpleStringProperty("");
        private BooleanProperty isMister = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        private BooleanProperty isMissus = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        private BooleanProperty isMiss = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        private StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty("");
        private StringProperty question = new SimpleStringProperty("");
        private ObservableList<String> questionList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        Model() {
            questionList.add("How was your day?");
            questionList.add("Would you like kippers for breakfast");
        }

        public StringProperty loopCountProperty() {
            return loopCount;
        }

        public BooleanProperty isMisterProperty() {
            return isMister;
        }

        public BooleanProperty isMissusProperty() {
            return isMissus;
        }

        public BooleanProperty isMissProperty() {
            return isMiss;
        }

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        public StringProperty questionProperty() {
            return question;
        }

        public ObservableList<String> getQuestionList() {
            return questionList;
        }

        public ObservableValue<String> greetingProperty() {
            return Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> buildGreeting(), loopCount, isMiss, isMissus, isMister, question, name);
        }

        private String buildGreeting() {
            int howMany;
            try {
                howMany = Integer.parseInt(loopCount.get());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "";
            }
            String title = "Master of Time and Space";
            if (isMiss.get()) {
                title = "Miss";
            }
            if (isMissus.get()) {
                title = "Mrs.";
            }
            if (isMister.get()) {
                title = "Mr.";
            }
            String greeting = "Hello " + title + " " + name.get() + " " + question.get();
            return IntStream.range(1, howMany + 1).mapToObj(idx -> idx + greeting).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        }
    }
}
```

So now the layout is just a layout, and all of the controls on the screen have their value properties bound to the Model.  Then the model has the code to put all the stuff together to create the result.  Technically, that code should belong in some sort of business logic class, but this should at least give you the idea.

I've left out the button because it doesn't really add any meaningful functionality, and it's slightly problematic to the UI.  There's no way to indicate if the result in the TextArea is current to the last button click.  For instance, you could click the button, then pick another title checkbox and now the selections on the screen don't match the TextArea.  But there's no way for the user to know this, and to implement it you'd probably have to go to something like the DirtyFX library.

But if you really want a button, then all you have to do is introduce a new StringProperty for the result, then have the button call Model.buildGreeting() in its EventHandler:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class GreeterButton extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Model model = new Model();
        ChoiceBox<String> questionChoiceBox = new ChoiceBox<>(model.questionList);
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea("");
        textArea.textProperty().bind(model.greetingProperty());
        Button button = new Button("Say Hi!");
        button.setOnAction(evt -> model.updateGreeting());
        VBox vBox = new VBox(20,
                             createBoundCheckBox("Miss", model.isMissProperty()),
                             createBoundCheckBox("Missus", model.isMissusProperty()),
                             createBoundCheckBox("Mister", model.isMisterProperty()),
                             questionChoiceBox,
                             createBoundTextField(model.nameProperty()),
                             createBoundTextField(model.loopCountProperty()),
                             button,
                             textArea);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vBox, 200, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @NotNull
    private Node createBoundCheckBox(String label, BooleanProperty boundProperty) {
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(label);
        boundProperty.bind(checkBox.selectedProperty());
        return checkBox;
    }

    private Node createBoundTextField(StringProperty boundProperty) {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        boundProperty.bind(textField.textProperty());
        return textField;
    }

    class Model {
        private StringProperty loopCount = new SimpleStringProperty("");
        private BooleanProperty isMister = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        private BooleanProperty isMissus = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        private BooleanProperty isMiss = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        private StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty("");
        private StringProperty question = new SimpleStringProperty("");
        private StringProperty greeting = new SimpleStringProperty("");
        private ObservableList<String> questionList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        Model() {
            questionList.add("How was your day?");
            questionList.add("Would you like kippers for breakfast");
        }

        public StringProperty loopCountProperty() {
            return loopCount;
        }

        public BooleanProperty isMisterProperty() {
            return isMister;
        }

        public BooleanProperty isMissusProperty() {
            return isMissus;
        }

        public BooleanProperty isMissProperty() {
            return isMiss;
        }

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        public StringProperty questionProperty() {
            return question;
        }

        public ObservableList<String> getQuestionList() {
            return questionList;
        }

        String buildGreeting() {
            int howMany;
            try {
                howMany = Integer.parseInt(loopCount.get());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "";
            }
            String title = "Master of Time and Space";
            if (isMiss.get()) {
                title = "Miss";
            }
            if (isMissus.get()) {
                title = "Mrs.";
            }
            if (isMister.get()) {
                title = "Mr.";
            }
            String greeting = "Hello " + title + " " + name.get() + " " + question.get();
            return IntStream.range(1, howMany + 1).mapToObj(idx -> idx + greeting).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        }

        public void updateGreeting() {
            greeting.set(buildGreeting());
        }

        public StringProperty greetingProperty() {
            return greeting;
        }
    }
}
```